# why my golang goroutine code get deadlocked

Tags: go, goroutine

I try to write some goroutine with channel, but get deadlocked, why?
Am I doing wrong with WaitGroup, so confused...

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func main() {
    chan1 := make(chan string)
    chan2 := make(chan string)
    chan3 := make(chan string, 2)
    wg.Add(1)
    go makeChanStr("yeye", chan1, chan3)
    wg.Add(1)
    go makeChanStr("okok", chan2, chan3)
    wg.Wait()
    close(chan3)
    println(<-chan1)
    println(<-chan2)
    for chs := range chan3 {
         println(chs)
    }
}

func makeChanStr(s string, c1 chan string, c2 chan string) {
    defer wg.Done()

    c1 <- "get " + s
    c2 <- "same value"
    fmt.Printf("execute ok %s", s)
}
```

Stackoverflow just don't let me submit the question.......so I just have to add some text.....

Comment: you're waiting for the goroutines to return before receiving from the channels. If you unblock that you're going to panic sending on a closed channel. Maybe start with a working example of concurrency, and modify it to suit your needs.

Comment: You're waiting for the goroutines to finish before reading from the channels, but the goroutines can't finish until they can send, and they can't send until something is ready to receive. The goroutines are waiting on each other, which is a deadlock.

Answer (score 4):

main block on `wg.Wait()`, which wait this two go routines to finish(because of `wg.Add(1)` and `wg.Done()`)

```
go makeChanStr("yeye", chan1, chan3)
go makeChanStr("okok", chan2, chan3)
```

but they block on `chan1` (or `chan2`) , because it's an unbuffer channel.

```
chan1 := make(chan string)
```

try change `chan1` and `chan2` to buffer channels:

```
chan1 := make(chan string,1)
chan2 := make(chan string,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This code blocks on `wg.Wait()` in main goroutine and writing to `c1` in workers. To avoid it - read from `c1` and `c2` prior to `wg.Wait()` thus unblock workers and they will not block on writing to buffered `c3`. As a result `wg.Done()` will be called and `wg.Wait()` will not block main goroutine as well.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func main() {
    chan1 := make(chan string)
    chan2 := make(chan string)
    chan3 := make(chan string, 2)
    wg.Add(1)
    go makeChanStr("yeye", chan1, chan3)
    wg.Add(1)
    go makeChanStr("okok", chan2, chan3)
    println(<-chan1)
    println(<-chan2)
    wg.Wait()
    close(chan3)
    for chs := range chan3 {
         println(chs)
    }
}

func makeChanStr(s string, c1 chan string, c2 chan string) {
    defer wg.Done()

    c1 <- "get " + s
    c2 <- "same value"
    fmt.Printf("execute %s\n", s)
}
```